# YouTube API start video at

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Currently I'm starting the embedded YouTube video for a couple seconds then automatically pausing it:

```
player.mute();
player.playVideo();
setTimeout(function(){
    player.seekTo(0,false);
    player.pauseVideo();
},6000); // 6 seconds
```

I then seek to second 0, but the problem is that when the `play` button is pressed, it starts at whatever second that it left off at. (So 6 seconds into the video in my case)
Instead, I want it so that the video will actually start at second 0 when play is pressed.

P.S. I have a reason for doing this, so please don't just comment "Why are you doing this?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pausing the Video instead of stopping, if you are stop that video it will starts from 0 seconds.

you can do this using `stopVideo()` function:

just change

```
player.pauseVideo();
```

To

```
player.stopVideo();
```